# Bring Price_at_Date from Price History in Sales Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Task: merge `Sales` and `Price_History` tables in `Revenue` view while introducing appropriate `Price_at_Date` from `Price_History` table

`Revenue` is a sample view.

Tables:

Price_History:

| Product_Name | Price | Price_Change_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 2021-09-01 |
| B | 120 | 2021-09-01 |
| A | 200 | 2021-09-05 |
| B | 250 | 2021-09-06 |

Sales:

| Product_Name | Qty | Sales_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 2021-09-02 |
| A | 12 | 2021-09-04 |
| B | 20 | 2021-09-03 |
| A | 25 | 2021-09-07 |
| B | 30 | 2021-09-09 |

Revenue: required

| Product_Name | Sale_Qty | Sales_Date | Price_at_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 2021-09-02 | 100 |
| A | 12 | 2021-09-04 | 100 |
| B | 20 | 2021-09-03 | 120 |
| A | 25 | 2021-09-07 | 200 |
| B | 30 | 2021-09-09 | 250 |

SQL queries:

```
CREATE TABLE Price_History 
(
    Product_Name Char(5),
    Price int,
    Price_Change_Date Date
)

INSERT INTO Price_History VALUES ('A', 100, '09-01-2021')
INSERT INTO Price_History VALUES ('B', 120, '09-01-2021')
INSERT INTO Price_History VALUES ('A', 200, '09-05-2021')
INSERT INTO Price_History VALUES ('B', 250, '09-06-2021')

CREATE TABLE Sales 
(
    Product_Name Char(5),
    Qty int,
    Sales_Date Date
)

INSERT INTO Sales VALUES ('A', 10, '09-02-2021')
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES ('A', 12, '09-04-2021')
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES ('B', 20, '09-03-2021')
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES ('A', 25, '09-07-2021')
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES ('B', 30, '09-09-2021')

CREATE TABLE Revenue 
(
    Product_Name Char(5),
    Sale_Qty int,
    Sales_Date Date,    
    Price_at_Date int
)

INSERT INTO Revenue VALUES ('A', 10, '09-02-2021', 100)
INSERT INTO Revenue VALUES ('A', 12, '09-04-2021', 100)
INSERT INTO Revenue VALUES ('B', 20, '09-03-2021', 120)
INSERT INTO Revenue VALUES ('A', 25, '09-07-2021', 200)
INSERT INTO Revenue VALUES ('B', 30, '09-09-2021', 250)
```

Comment: So what have you done so far to answer this homework question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `TOP 1` `APPLY` should do the trick:

```sql
CREATE VIEW Revenue
AS

SELECT
  s.Product_Name,
  s.Qty,
  s.Sales_Date,
  ph.Price
FROM Sales s
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
      ph.Price
    FROM Price_History ph
    WHERE ph.Product_Name = s.Product_Name
      AND ph.Price_Change_Date <= s.Sales_Date
    ORDER BY ph.Price_Change_Date DESC
) ph;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1a6c258aa1f37713f1b895386d1c458)

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_name, sale_qty, sales_date, price "price_at_date"
from (
    select s,*, p.price, 
        row_number() over (partition by s.product_name, s.sales_date order by p.price_change_date desc)
    from sales s
    inner join price_history p on p.product_name = s.product_name and p.price_change_date <= s.sales_date
) t
where t.rn = 1
```